# Sql error "invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Anyone idea why am I getting error ?

```
create or replace view PROD as
  select
    mytable.name as description
  from table_name mytable
  join another_table another on another.id in (
      select mytable1.id
      from table_name mytable1
      start with mytable1.id = mytable.id
      connect by prior mytable1.id = mytable1.parent_id);
Error at Command Line:8 Column:41
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MYTABLE"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This actually works for my local database installation. However, not on any other. Running on Oracle database.

Thank you

Comment: try using a different alias: `table` is a reserved word, so it's better not to use it as an alias

Comment: also `desc` is a reserved keyword which is the next error you would encounter after changing the table alias.

Comment: I just change to table as i dont want to expose real name

Comment: Just tested on 11g XE, it works. Which Oracle version?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: I will try 11g XE too. For version elimination.

Comment: Are you trying to run this from a different user? Do you need to fully qualify the names (add the schema name before the table name)?

Comment: The problem with changing names when posting a question is that it's easy to accidentally hide the real problem. I understand the need, but it has to be done carefully and consistently, and ideally you should check you can still reproduce the problem with the fake names. Double-check the spelling and aliases used, and also check you don't have quoted identifiers to worry about.

Comment: Apparently in the 'any other' databases, the table MYTABLE doesn't have an `ID` field. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version problem:

1. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 -
   Production
2. Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
   Production

Where 1. is the one where this syntax does not work.